# embed google font in ggplotly png download

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am able to use css in `flexdashboard` to render a `ggplotly` object with my preferred Google font, but I'm not sure how to embed the font so that downloading a png using the plotly toolbar creates an image with the font.

Flexdashboard, correct font on axis ticks:

[image]

Downloaded plot from plotly toolbar, incorrect font:

[image]

````
---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
---

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,700');

body{ /* Normal  */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight:200;
}
</style>

```{r}
  library(tidyverse)
  library(plotly)
  library(flexdashboard)
```


### Chart 1

```{r}
  f <- list(family = "Poppins")
  a <- list(tickfont = f)

  p <- ggplot(fortify(forecast::gold), aes(x, y)) + 
         geom_line() +
         theme(axis.text = element_text(family = "Poppins",
                                        size = rel(.9),
                                        color = "#575656"))

  ggplotly(p) %>%
    layout(font=f, xaxis = a, yaxis = a)
```
````